# retrieve data from database based on user check at checkbox and display in google chart

Tags: php, mysql, json, checkbox, google-visualization

I got this google chart visualization code and also json table that will accept data from multiple user selected via checkbox and ****retrieve the data result from database based on what they check at checkbox and display by google chart in form of column chart..****

The problem is, the column chart just display the last element data of checkbox only for ****example if I tick BAS and BAT checkbox, the column chart just only display BAT data.****it is suppose to display BAS and BAT data..where is my error..below this is the code..:- Thank u very much for your time..

```
<div class="SamHistogramDiv" id="SamHistogramDiv">  
<?php
if(isset($_GET['iddoc']))
{       
    foreach ($_GET['iddoc'] as $iddoc)
    {

       $query="select * from compareresult where iddocument=$iddoc";
       $sql_query = mysql_query($query) or die('Error 3 :'.mysql_error());
       $rows = array();             
       $flag = true;
       $table = array();
       $table['cols'] = array
       (
            array('label' => 'title', 'type' => 'string'),
            array('label' => 'percentage', 'type' => 'number')
       );
       $rows = array();
       while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_query)) 
       {
            $temp = array();
            $temp[] = array('v' => (string)$r['subject']);
            $temp[] = array('v' => (int)$r['result']); 
            $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);          
       }    
       $table['rows'] = $rows;
       $jsonTable = json_encode($table);    
   }    
?>
</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart()
    {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?php echo $jsonTable ?>);
        var options =
        {
            title: 'Comparison Result',
            is3D: 'true',
            width: 800,
            height: 600
        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('SamHistogramDiv'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: This isn't the problem, but you have the line `$rows = array();` twice, where you should only need one of them. Also, I am correct in assuming that `$_GET['iddoc']` is your list of checked boxes? It seems that you are setting `$jsonTable` to only one set of rows at a time, and then overwriting it with the data from the next selected checkbox. You would have to build the rows to add first, and then either append them to the existing table or add them all at once to `$jsonTable`

Comment: @jaredk .. yes..! u are correct... $_GET['iddoc'] is my list of checked boxes..so then i must delete one of the $rows = array();..?? is it like that...?which one should i delete..?

Comment: It won't solve the problem with only displaying the last checkbox's data, but removing either one should be fine.

Comment: @jaredk but in    $_GET['iddoc'] .. it hold all selected checkbox id,not just one selected checkbox only.. so it should display all..

Comment: My apologies, I had misread your code earlier. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your current code is that you are looping through your checkboxes, getting the data for each one, and then encoding and storing it in `$jsonTable`, but then you are declaring your `$table` array again every iteration. This overwrites the data that you had stored previously each new iteration.

Try something like this instead:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['iddoc']))
{    
    $table = array();
    $table['cols'] = array
    (
        array('label' => 'title', 'type' => 'string'),
        array('label' => 'percentage', 'type' => 'number')
    );

    foreach ($_GET['iddoc'] as $iddoc)
    {
        $query="select * from compareresult where iddocument=$iddoc";
        $sql_query = mysql_query($query) or die('Error 3 :'.mysql_error());

        while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_query)) 
        {
            $temp = array();
            $temp[] = array('v' => (string)$r['subject']);
            $temp[] = array('v' => (int)$r['result']); 
            $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);          
        }    
        $table['rows'] = $rows;            
    }

    $jsonTable = json_encode($table);
}
?>
```

You could also try getting the data from all of your checkbox ID's at the same time and doing away with the `foreach` loop entirely by using the SQL `IN` statement. I will leave the exact method of it up to you but the syntax would be something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM compareresult WHERE iddocument IN ('1', '2', '3');
```

You would have to do add some code to get the array in `$_GET['iddoc']` into a format that works with your SQL statement, but it should allow you to parse all of the data at once without making multiple calls to your database.

Comment: owhh...i see... i am a newbie in programming, u can see i still using msql instead mysqli or pdo.. your code is just works for me..!! :) i'll try to use the IN statement also.. thank u very much for your help dear.. :)